# How can we minimize the gutter-width in bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can we minimize the gutter-width in bootstrap 3 ? As Bootstrap follows 12-grids system, so when i put my content using col-sm-* it makes a gap between the elements by some pixels (let's say 30px i.e 15px on either side of the grid-column) but the requirement of my theme doesn't require too much space between the columns. sO, What should i do to minimize that space ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to generate a custom Bootstrap build, here is a CSS technique that will override the Bootstrap padding (gutter) between columns..

```
/* remove spacing between middle columns */
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  padding-right:0;
  padding-left:0;
}
/* remove right padding from first column */
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:first-child {
  padding-right:0;
}
/* remove left padding from last column */
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:last-child {
  padding-left:0;
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/109530

Another option (reduce gutter to half - 15px):

```
.row-smaller {
    margin-left: -7.5px;
    margin-right: -7.5px;
}

.row-smaller > div[class^="col"] {
    padding-left: 7.5px;
    padding-right: 7.5px;
}
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/pb9pQzThUy

This technique also works in **Bootstrap 4**: https://www.codeply.com/go/SZcY3X4hTY

Answer (score 0):

Use the [bootstrap customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/).

In this editor edit the `@grid-gutter-width` value.

Comment: sir where should i give this value ? In my customize style sheet(mystyle.css) or should i download a customized version of bootstrap.css from the official site with the hard-coded value of gutter-width ?? Please elaborate ..

Comment: You go this page : http://getbootstrap.com/customize/
Set the @grid-gutter-width to the value you want to use.
Download the custom bootstrap generated by this trick and replace your Bootstrap lib by the new one.

Comment: yeah i was thinking this. Thanks for assisting me bro :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using sass, look for the word `gutter` in `bootstrap\scss\_variables.scss`. Copy and overwrite the necessary variables to your own sass files without the `!default`.